# In python, what does this do: tan_y[:-1][np.diff(tan_y) < 0]

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, trigonometry

While learning how to simply graph a tan function using matplotlib I stumbled upon this line of code tan_y[:-1][np.diff(tan_y) < 0] which I found online. I just want to know what **each part** of the code does

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#In Degrees
x = np.linspace(0,360,600)
tan_y = np.tan(x*(np.pi/180))
tan_y[:-1][np.diff(tan_y) < 0] = np.nan #Not quite sure what the start of this function does

plt.plot(x,tan_y,linewidth = 3) #Plot tan function

plt.ylim(-20,20)
plt.xlabel('X', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 12)
plt.ylabel(r'$\sin(x)$', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 12)
plt.title('Wave', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This line is doing nothing to your variables.  I think it was a debug line to ensure that all values were increasing.  Basically it check to see if all the values of tan_y are increasing, if not, then show places where tan_y is decreasing.

Comment: np.diff subtacts the current value from the next, and since there is no next of the last value, they are using [:-1] to drop that value.  using the < 0 to see all values are increasing and boolean index the array to return any places where tan_y is descreasing.

Answer (score 2):

**Program syntax explanation**

1. `tan_y` is a `numpy.dnarray`, it represents the ordinates of the mathematical [tan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) function, previously defined. It is a 600 element long array.
2. `tan_y[:-1]` extracts each element of the array, until the last, excluded. Since, in Python, the stop element of a loop is exclusive, this is a way to drop the last element of an array, see this example:

   ```
   for i in range(5):
       print(i)

   0
   1
   2
   3
   4
   ```

   Number `5` it is not printed because it is the stop element of the loop.
   So, `tan_y[:-1]` is a way to remove the last element of this array, therefore `tan_y[:-1]` is 599 element long.
3. `np.diff(tan_y)` calculates the 'derivative' of `tan_y`, see the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). It takes the i-th element and subtracts the previous one (i-1)-th, as in this example:

   ```
   import numpy as np

   x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 4, -1])
   dx = np.diff(x)

   print(dx)

   [ 1  1  3  3 -4 -5]
   ```

   As you can see, the results is an array in which each element is the result of a difference between each element of `x` and its previous. Important note: the result `dx` is 1 element shorter then `x`, because of the way the calculation is done. This is the reason why you need to remove the last element of the `tan_y` at the previous point: `tan_y` and `np.diff(tan_y)` have to have the same length in order to be compared. In this case both are 599 element long.
4. `np.diff(tan_y) < 0` generates a boolean array of the same length of `np.diff(tan_y)`, in this case 599, where:

   - if a i-th element of `np.diff(tan_y)` is positive, the i-th element of `np.diff(tan_y) < 0` is set to `False`
   - if a i-th element of `np.diff(tan_y)` is negative, the i-th element of `np.diff(tan_y) < 0` is set to `True`

   This is a way to create a filter: an array of `True` and `False` according to a specified condition.
5. `tan_y[:-1][np.diff(tan_y) < 0]` applies the filter you created at the point 4. to the array you generated in the point 2. In order to do this, both arrays have to have the same length, 599 element long in this case.
6. `tan_y[:-1][np.diff(tan_y) < 0] = np.nan` sets to `NaN` the elements of `tab_y` where its derivative is negative.

---

**Mathematical meaning**

So far so good? If I have not lost you in the explanation of the Python language, we move forward to the mathematical part.
I assume you know that `tan(x)` is a *increasing monotone function*. This means it is rising in all its *domain*. In other words, its derivative must be always positive in its domain.
If you try to run the code, without that line of code, you will see something like this:

[image]

What are those vertical lines in correspondence of the asymptotes of the function? This appens because `plt.plot()` does not know it is plotting a `tan(x)`, which has asymptotes. `plt.plot()` simply draws a line between each point of the curve you specify.
In order to better understanding this, I replot the previuos plot, with a small number of points (30) and this options:

```
plt.plot(x,tan_y,'o-',linewidth = 2)
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Pretty ugly, uh? Usually, if you want to *hide the dust under the carpet*, you increase the number of points, this improves the *resolution* of the curve. Despite this, the vertical lines remain. So, the line

```
tan_y[:-1][np.diff(tan_y) < 0] = np.nan
```

is a way to set to `NaN` the values of `tan_y` when its derivative is negative: exactly in correspondence of the vertical lines, so as to remove them!
With this filter, the graph becomes:

[image]

a clean, smooth `tan(x)` graph without its asymptotes.